# Selecionar tr de una tabla con javaScript si tiene un texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy tratando de cambiar el estilo de toda una fila específica si es que, dentro de esa fila, un elemento contiene un texto plano que recibo a través de un parámetro en la url.

Con este código extraigo la variable oculta en la url.

```js
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var idDeny = query.split("=");
var psf=idDeny.pop();
```

Ahora quiero buscar esa variable dentro de las filas de mi tabla y cuando la encuentre: que modifique su estilo sombreándolo un poco para indicarle al usuario dónde está ese elemento.

Estaba intentando algo como esto:

```js
$("#tSearch tr").find(psf) {
    $(this).css('background-color','#000');
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Muéstranos tu código, por favor.

Comment: El valor que obtenés en la variable `psf`, ya tiene el `#` antes del nombre del id, o hay que agregarlo?

Comment: @Yami, ¿el ID es el de la fila o el de un elemento dentro de la fila? Las respuestas que tienes hasta ahora son para las filas con el ID que obtienes en psf, pero lo que yo entiendo es que ese ID es el de un campo/elemento dentro de esa fila, que no es lo mismo y se haría de manera diferente

Comment: @Yami - modifiqué tu pregunta en base a los comentarios que hiciste para aclarar lo que estabas buscando. Si hay algo erróneo en la edición, no dudes en comentarlo/cambiarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Para encontrar texto dentro de un elemento de la fila

Se puede utilizar el selector [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Así:

```
$("#tSearch").find('tr:contains("' + psf + '")')
```

seleccionamos la tabla con id `tSearch` y luego seleccionamos las filas que contienen el texto asignado a `psf`.

#### Código

```js
// A modo de ejemplo, buscamos la fila que tiene el texto "B1"
var psf = 'B1';

// Cambiar el fondo
$("#tSearch").find('tr:contains("' + psf + '")')
             .css('background-color','#ff0');
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tSearch">
  <tr id="titulo">
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fila1">
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fila2">
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona :'D

Answer (score 1):

Optimizando un poco el código, y teniendo en cuenta que estás trabajando con el atributo `id`, puedes usar el selector directamente (deberías tener solo un elemento con dicho `id` en tu documento):

Solución con jQuery

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var idDeny = query.split("=");
var psf = idDeny.pop();

$('#' + pst).css('background-color','#000');
```

Solución con javaScript puro

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var idDeny = query.split("=");
var psf = idDeny.pop();

document.getElementById(psf).style.backgroundColor = "#000";
```

Comment: Aún así el código debe funcionar, pues no es mas que un `id="algo"`.